# Convert array take string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I would like to know how to convert my array to a string

```
   $formats = $_POST['formats'];
      $topics = $_POST['topics'];
```

for example, if I echo out the above, it just prints array. I want it to display the array as a string so that I could use it below:

```
 $resources = "select * from resources where stage LIKE '%".$stage."%' and formats LIKE '%".$formats."%' and topics LIKE '%".$topics."%'";
```

I have been suggested to do something like this        `$formats = $_POST['formats'][0];`
but i want to output the entire array as a string such `"idea generation, business"` would be equivilant to `["idea generation", business"]`

Comment: You shoud search about prepared statements and query parameters before taking any step further.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array to String PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490488/array-to-string-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it isn't possible to determine which database you're using to make that query happen, I'll suggest you to build your query string using *prepared statements* and *paremeterizing your values* to a `PDO` object based on what you may read in [PHP.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) on the subject.

> Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark
>   placeholder in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the
>   statement. Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as
>   a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that
>   PDOStatement::execute() is called.

As you'll see, that way you won't have to bother converting your **arrays** and **variables** to **string** before accessing them, plus, you grant security to your query statements.

So, instead of `implode`ing a string, you'll have something like this:

```
<?php
    /* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
    $stage = $_POST['stage'];
    $formats = $_POST['formats'];
    $topics = $_POST['topics'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare('select * from resources where stage LIKE % :stage % and formats LIKE % :formats % and topics LIKE % :topics %');
    $stmt->bindParam(':stage', $stage);
    $stmt->bindParam(':formats', $formats);
    $stmt->bindParam(':topics', $topics);
    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

**EDIT**: as you updated that you're using MySQLi, it'll be no different.

```
$stmt = $mysqli_db->prepare('select * from resources where stage LIKE % ? % and formats LIKE % ? % and topics LIKE % ? %');
// assuming all your params are strings
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $stage, $formats, $topics);
$stmt->execute();
```

As using mysqli, since it's an unbuffered sql query handler, you should store your results if you're looping simultaneous executions with `$stmt->store_result();`

Any doubts about how to use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) objects, methods and properties can be easily found in php.net documentation (linked above).

Of course, it's just a suggeston of better practices based on your apparent needs, but you can still use the [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to achieve your string.

Comment: hi thanks a lot for your response. I am using mysqli to connect to the database not PDO.

Comment: It might not be different in the end, just syntactically distinct :)

Comment: thanks but how would this be integrated with my mysqli while loop?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at PHP `implode` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

For example, this will turn an array into a string, separating each element with a comma:

`$string = implode(',', $array);`