# How to convert array to string

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to PHP.

I want to convert this array [["14785"],["125478"]] to string like this 14785,125478.

What is the way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array to String PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490488/array-to-string-php)

Comment: Show your real array structure..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this,

Using `implode()` - **[Demo](https://eval.in/481388)**

```
$array = ["14785"],["125478"]
$str = implode(',',$array);
echo $str;
```

Using `join()` - **[Demo](https://eval.in/481389)**

```
$array =  ["14785","125478"];
$str = join(",",$array);
echo $str;
```

**EDIT**

For multi-dimention array, - **[Demo](https://eval.in/481554)**

```
$arr = [["14785"],["125478"]];
$str = implode(',', array_map(function($el){ return $el[0]; }, $arr));

echo $str;
```

Comment: When I use implode function I get an error like Array to string conversion. my code is an array inside array.I have edited it properly now.

Comment: can you format the array which you have added in proper way??

Comment: This is my code [["14785"],["125478"]] I want like this 14785 so that I can compare it with another value.

Comment: Glad I could help you:)

Comment: if its single dimention, use first method, if its multi dimention, use `array_map()` method.

Comment: yes but the problem I got again is length of that string is one not two.I want two separate strings.How would I solve this?

Comment: I used implode function for multi-dimention array [["14785","2222"],["125478"]] but I got answer like this 14785,125478.where expected answer is like this 14785,2222,125478. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

use php's `implode` function

```
$arr =  ["14785","125478"];
echo implode(",",$arr);
```

Comment: Without knowing the array structure it may not work, but for normal arrays this is the way..

Comment: join is faster than implode: http://dev.airve.com/demo/speed_tests/php/join_vs_implode.php `echo join(",",$arr);`

Comment: @MyWay - `join()` is simply an alias for `implode()` so why do you believe that it's faster based on that arbitrary test page that you've linked..... the executed code is the same

Comment: Mentioned what I came across

Comment: The link you came across is a pretty arbitrary tester that isn't consistent from one run to the next, so it can't be taken as absolute gospel truth.... it's meaningless

Comment: func2() took 1.014 times longer than func1(), func2() took 0.979 times longer than func1(), func2() took 1.003 times longer than func1(), func2() took 1.702 times longer than func1(), func2() took 0.966 times longer than func1()

Answer (score 0):

Using implode()

```
 <?php
$arr = array('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');
echo implode(" ",$arr);
?>
```