# How can i align variables in the array side by side and assign to variable

Tags: php

```
$dizi=array();
$a=2;
$dizi[]= $a;
$dizi[]= 4;
$dizi[]= 7;
```

Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 7 )

how can i assing to variable like :

```
$variable=247
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7490488/3933332

Comment: echo implode("",$dizi); looking for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can implode an array on a delimiter. If you provide no delimiter, it concatenates all the values together.

```
$variable = implode('',$dizi);

Outputs: $variable = 247;
```

Answer (score 0):

make a variable and set it equal to `implode("", $array); now if you echo the variable the result will be values of array without space or line-break.

```
$dizi=array();
$a=2;
$dizi[]= $a;
$dizi[]= 4;
$dizi[]= 7;

$variable = implode("", $dizi);
echo $variable;
```

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to provide more info

Answer (score 0):

The implode() function returns a string from the elements of an array.

```
$variable = implode("", $dizi);
```

**Output**

```
$variable=247
```

You can also try the join function.

The join() function returns a string from the elements of an array.

```
$variable = join("", $dizi);
```

**Output**

```
$variable=247
```

> The join() function is an alias of the implode() function.

Answer (score 0):

Though [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is the best way, i have tried using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$variable=str_replace(array('[', ']',','), '', json_encode($dizi));
```

> Outputs: $variable = 247;

Comment: @dogacan7 any updates ? Accept and up-vote if helped! thanks!