# Implode column values with commas

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, implode, array-column

I have below array,

```
Array
(
 [1] => Array
  (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [location] => X33
            [usernumber] => 1
            [order] => XX
            [part_number] => Hi
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [location] => X33
            [usernumber] => 1
            [order] => YY
            [part_number] => 68730
        )

  )
```

I want desired output string to echo as below,

```
'Hello ur oder - XX, YY, part number-Hi, 68730'
```

How to achieve this output? I was thinking to run a `foreach` loop, but I'm not sure how I could convert this to a string.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1494953/3933332 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7490488/3933332

Comment: @Rizier123, got it will get array and then implode it!

Comment: Something like `'Hello, ur order - '.implode(", ", array_column($arr[1], 'order')).', '.part number-'.implode(", ", array_column($arr[1], 'part_number'))."'"`

Comment: It does not look senseful. There is one costomer with 2 different orders, each ordering one item. It might be more applicable in scripts probably based on database to fetch the records without a JOIN clause doing a nested fetch loop. What is the real intention?

Answer (score 4):

Run a foreachloop and concat

```
$orderNumber = '';
$partnumber = '';
foreach ($yourArray as $array) {
    if ($orderNumber !="") {
        $orderNumber.=",";
    }
    $orderNumber.= $array['order'];
    if ($partNumber !="") {
        $partNumber.=",";
    }
    $partNumber.= $array['part_number'];
}
echo "Hello ur order - ".$orderNumber." part number-". $partNumber;
```

Comment: That won't work for his array structure. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3cefbebf84f100bcaf51ec9d98288aae919d4413

Comment: You must add separete ", "

Comment: Like : `'Hello, ur order - '.implode(", ", array_column($arr[1], 'order')).', '.part number-'.implode(", ", array_column($arr[1], 'part_number'))."'"`

Comment: @MaximTkach  added fix for comma (",");

Comment: @chandresh_cool yes, its good. And yet, he had an array of arrays

Comment: yes and I believe he should be wise enough to retrieve array of array.

Answer (score 0):

Your must help this code:

```
<?php
    $array = [
        [
            [
                'order'       => 1,
                'part_number' => 1
            ],
            [
                'order'       => 2,
                'part_number' => 2
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $orders = [];
    $partnumber = [];
    foreach($array as $v) {
        foreach($v as $item) {
            $orders[] = $item['order'];
            $partnumber[] = $item['part_number'];
        }
    }
    $str = sprintf("Hello ur oder - %s, part number-%s", implode(', ', $orders), implode(', ', $partnumber));
    echo $str;
```

Result:

```
Hello ur oder - 1, 2, part number-1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

@Frayne Konoks Solution is a nice oneliner:

His Solution with quotes fixed :)

```
echo 'Hello, ur order - '.implode(", ", array_column($var[1], 'order')).', '.'part number-'.implode(", ", array_column($var[1], 'part_number'))."'";
```

`$var` is your array.

Working example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c95545bdf9d9216d6c80cc06542517e596a0360a

Comment: I think this is bad route. If there is no element 1, and there is an element 2? I like my answer :)

Comment: @FrayneKonok When you add an answer to this im gonna delete mine.

Comment: @MaximTkach, You should know about some loop, you need to use the loop for catching the first dimension.

Comment: @FrayneKonok Yes, but your answer did not include loop. So your example of narrowly specialized, only a concrete example ... But maybe its ok

Comment: I am not making any answer, cause its already suggested by @Rizier123.

Comment: Maybe it will be interesting:
https://progblog.net/2014/08/array_column-performance-of-built-in-functions/

Comment: Oops i miss to up you.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the array structure a little bit. The code below would be of help:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'location' => 'X33',
        'usernumber' => '1',
        'order' => 'XX',
        'part_number' => 'Hi',
    ),
    array(
        'location' => 'X33',
        'usernumber' => '1',
        'order' => 'YY',
        'part_number' => '68730',
    )
);

$order = '';
$p_no = '';
foreach ($arr as $ar) {
    $order .= $ar['order'] . ',';
    $p_no .= $ar['part_number'] . ',';
}

$order = rtrim($order, ',');
$p_no = rtrim($p_no, ',');
$final_str = 'Hello ur order - ' . $order . ' part number - ' . $p_no;
echo $final_str;
```

Answer (score -1):

It's as simple as:

```
foreach($array[1] as $item){
   echo "Hello ur order - " . $item["order"] . ", " $item["location"] . ", part number-" . $item["order"] . ", " . $item["part_number"];
}
```

Comment: That won't work for his array structure. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6315761a1e88b4b784d5915f37fb8e536f74f6bd

Comment: Edited! Thanks! :)