# PHP array convert each to string

Tags: php, arrays

Simple question in PHP, how to convert this below array to be string?

```
print_r($_POST['cb']);

//result
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [tipe] => create ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [tipe] => delete ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [tipe] => read ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 2 [tipe] => delete ) )
```

I tried this below code but not working:

```
echo implode(", ", $_POST['cb']);

//result
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [tipe] => read
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [tipe] => update
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [tipe] => update
    )

)
```

What I want is to get id and tipe for each array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array to String PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490488/array-to-string-php)

Comment: so you want a string like "1 read 1 update 2 update" ??

Comment: @AmrAly Yes correct. Please advice

Answer (score 1):

What you could is initialize an empty string and then loop through your arrays and add their elements to your initialized string like this :

```
$str = '';
foreach($arrs as $arr) { // $arrs is your $_POST['cb'] array
    foreach($arr as $item) {
        $str .= $item . ' ';
    }
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how about to save it to database? ex: INSERT INTO T_DATA(ID, CHKVALUE) VALUES('', '') <--

Comment: if you need to save the data into  database then what  you need is to save them as a variables not a string for example $id = $_POST['id'].

Comment: Would you give me an example?

Comment: for example `INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)
VALUES (4,'$name', 25, '$address', 6500.00 );`

Comment: I mean example in this case please. :)

Comment: Your data in this case is not easy to be stored in a variable it's better to structure your code so the submitted data will be a normal array and not a multidimensional array. i hope that makes sense. i have a question is that all your data submitted to your server?

Comment: if so what you could do create your variables is `$id = $_POST['cb'][0]['id']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137201/discussion-between-hidayurie-dave-and-amr-aly).

Comment: How the $id set for each?

Answer (score 0):

```
class StringBuilder {

    private $data;
    private $string;

    function __construct(array $data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function get() {
        $this->parse();
        return $this->string;
    }

    private function parse() {
        foreach($this->data as $values) {
            $this->string .= $values['id'] . ' ' . $values['tipe'] . ' '; 
        }
        $this->string = trim($this->string);
    }
}
```

I think this would be the easiest way for you to achieve what you are attempting to do.

Available Methods:

- __construct()
- get()