# How to echo the message in this json

Tags: php, json

I have a json response how do i echo the response in `message` i tried `json_encode` but it seems not working

```
{
    "success": "verification_error",
    "message": [
        "required.",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Which technology are you working with ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. sorry my bad PHP

Answer (score 0):

I think you mix `json_encode` and `json_decode`.

- [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php) is used to create a `json` object (from an array for example).
- [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php) do the opposite: decode a `json` object.

Another point is that the `message` field is an array. You can not directly display `array` as `string`.

1. In your example, you only have one element in the array. So you can directly display it by selecting it (with index).
2. If the array has more than one element, you can either iterate over the array and apply the first case or [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array to a string. Some discussion about the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490488/array-to-string-php).

Here an example:

```
<?php

$a = array("success"=> "verification_error",
    "message"=> [
        "required.",
    ]
);

$json_response = json_encode($a);
echo("Your response (json encoded): ".$json_response);
// Your response (json encoded): {"success":"verification_error","message":["required."]}

$data = json_decode($json_response, true);
echo("<br/>Message: ".$data["message"][0]);
// Message: required.
?>
```