# Difficulty converting array to string

Tags: php

how can i convert this array to string?

```
public static function generos($string) {
   return preg_replace(array("/(natacao)/"),explode(" ","Natação"), $string);
}

public function categoria($string) {
    $this->exp = explode(",", $string);
    foreach ($this->exp as $this->list) :
        return $this->generos(implode(",", $this->list));
    endforeach;
}

echo '<li>'.$this->categoria($rows[] = $this->row['categoria']).'</li>';
```

**table**

```
id  |  categoria  
 1  |  futebol, voleiball
```

Current results

```
<li>futebol, voleiball</li>
```

expected result

```
<li>futebol</li>
<li>voleiball</li>
```

Comment: `implode("</li>\n<li>", $this->list)`

Comment: Where is `<li>` and `</li>` coming from? I don't see it anywhere in the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array to String PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490488/array-to-string-php)

Comment: The `return` statement is ending the `foreach` loop during the first iteration. I don't see how you're getting both `futebol` and `voleiball` in the output.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to store comma-separated lists in a database column. You should normalize your data. But that's a separate issue from this problem.

Comment: `implode(",", $this->list)` makes no sense. `$this->list` is a string, but the second argument to `implode()` should be an array.

Comment: @Barmar `string(19) "futebol, voleiball"
    return var_dump($this->generos(implode(",", $this->exp)));`

Comment: @AbraCadaver exactly what I need

Comment: `$this->exp` is a list, but `$this->list` is one of the elements of that list, which is just a string.

Answer (score 1):

add your array's value to another variable like this:

```
<?php
    $dizi=array('mother','father','child'); //This is array

    $sayi=count($dizi);
    for ($i=0; $i<$sayi; $i++) {
        $dizin.=("'$dizi[$i]',"); //Now it is string...
    }
         echo substr($dizin,0,-1); //Write it like string :D
?>
```

In this code we added $dizi's values and comma to $dizin:

`$dizin.=("'$dizi[$i]',");`

Now

```
$dizin = 'mother', 'father', 'child',
```

It's a string, but it has an extra comma :)

And then we deleted the last comma, `substr($dizin, 0, -1);`

Output:

> 'mother','father','child'