# using array in where condition

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I have an array data called `$req_dep`. Here's what it look like when I `var_dump()` it.

```
array(2) { [0]=> int(41) [1]=> int(765) }
```

I want to use that data in query

```
  select * from dbo.RequisitionTable 
  where RequestorID = '$ID'
  and RequestorDepartmentID in ($req_dep)
  and IsProcessedToHire=0 
  and IsHold = 0
  and IsRejected = 0
```

But it always get error `"Array to string conversion"`. How to use array in where condition like that?

Thank You

Comment: implode it in, or better yet use the active record of codeigniter and use the `$this->db->where_in()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array to String PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490488/array-to-string-php)

Comment: @Kevin idea has help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query:

```
select * from dbo.RequisitionTable 
where RequestorID = '$ID'
and RequestorDepartmentID in ($req_dep)
and IsProcessedToHire=0 
and IsHold = 0
and IsRejected = 0
```

Can easily be converted to CodeIgniter's query builder like this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('dbo.RequisitionTable');
$this->db->where('RequestorID', $ID);
$this->db->where_in('RequestorDepartmentID', $req_dep);
$this->db->where('IsProcessedToHire', 0);
$this->db->where('IsHold', 0);
$this->db->where('IsRejected', 0);
```

The above assumes $ID and $req_dep are passed to the model and that the latter is an array

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Query builder class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) ? You can do that by,

```
$conds = [
   "RequestorID" => $ID,
   "IsProcessedToHire" => 0,
   "IsHold" => 0,
   "IsRejected" => 0  
];

$result = $this->db->where($conds)->where_in("RequestorDepartmentID", $req_dep)->get("RequisitionTable")->result_array();
```