# How to store array value in variable?

Tags: php, arrays

I got the values like following and need to store in single variable like $value = "Corporis dolore nemo","Cupidatat atque enim","Rerum consequatur I"

```
Array
(
    [0] => Corporis dolore nemo
    [1] => Cupidatat atque enim
    [2] => Rerum consequatur I
)
```

I tried using following code but it give array to string conversion error.

```
    foreach($value['title'] as $val)
           {
               $me[] = $val  ;
           }
$model->title = $me;
```

Comment: Check this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490488/array-to-string-php) out.

Comment: Check this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490488/array-to-string-php) out.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$model->title = implode(", ", $value['title']);
```

This makes it so you don't need the `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $arr = array('Test1','Test2','Test3','Test4');
    echo implode(", ",$arr);
?>
```

The implode() function returns a string from an array.

The explode() function splits a string into an array.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490488/array-to-string-php) out also.