# PHP Regex pattern needed for MySQL database manupilation

Tags: php, regex, database, denormalized

I have some columns in my table, **descriptions** column contains some information like;

```
a1b01,Value 1,2,1,60|a1b01,Value2,1,1,50|b203c,Value 1,0,2,20
```

with a SQL command, i need to update it.

In there, I'll use a PHP function for updating, if first and second parameters exist in current records (in description column) together.

Eg: if user wants to change the value of description that includes `a1b01,Value 1` I'll execute a SQL command like that;

```
function do_action ($code,$value,$new1,$new2,$newresult) {
UPDATE the_table SET descriptions = REPLACE(descriptions, $code.','.$value.'*', $code.','.$value.','.$new1.','.$new2.','.$newresult)";
}
```

- (star) indicates that, these part is unknown (This is why i need a regex)

My question is : how can i get

```
a1b01,Value 1,2,1,60|
```

part from below string

```
a1b01,Value 1,2,1,60|a1b01,Value2,1,1,50|b203c,Value 1,0,2,20
```

via regex, but `a1b01` and `Value 1` should be get as parameter.

I just want that; when I call `do_action` like that;

```
do_action ("a1b01","Value 1",2,3,25);
```

record will be : **`a1b01,Value 1,2,3,25`**`|a1b01,Value2,1,1,50|b203c,Value 1,0,2,20`
(*first part is updated...*)

Comment: Why are you storing serialized values in an RDBMS? Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364803/storing-arrays-in-the-database/7364834#7364834 . If you had your tables designed the right way, you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to use a regular expression to do this, you could use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function since it is all delimited

So you could do as follows:

```
$descriptionArray = explode('|', $descriptions); //creates array of the a1b01,Value 1,2,1,60 block
//then for each description explode on ,
for($i = 0; i < count($descriptionArray); $i++){
    $parameters = explode(',', $descriptionArray[$i]); 
    do_action ($parameters[0],$parameters[1],$parameters[2],$parameters[3],$parameters[4]);
}
```

Comment: i was just about to write the same code block, kudos - up vote

Comment: you could just not do the loop and make it `$descriptionArray[0]` if it's not needed and i'm understanding the amended logic ;)